# What does the -t:go flag do in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I couldn't find it mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019

But it is used here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-t` is the short form for the `-target` switch, which tells MSBuild what target to build.
Excerpt from the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019):

> ```
> Switch                 Short Form        Description
> ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> -target:targets        -t:targets        Build the specified targets in
>                                          the project. Specify each target
>                                          separately, or use a semicolon or
>                                          comma to separate multiple targets, 
>                                          as the following example shows:
> ```

So `msbuild MyProject.proj -t:go` will call the `go` target in the project `MyProject.proj`.